# How is the getBatteryLevel() function implemented on Android?

Tags: java, android, operating-system

I am looking for the implementation of how android is communicating with the battery and the logic it uses to determine the battery level.

I am not looking how to write an app that gives the battery level, I am looking to understand how the os calculate the battery level to begin with.

I looked in:

```
BatteryManagerInternal.java
BatteryManager.java
BatteryProperties.java
```

and I see that it is retrieving it but I cant find the actual logic, or communication with the battery PCB.

Thank you for the help!
Idan.

Comment: The Android documentation has some pretty good info on the subject. [link](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `BatteryManagerInternal` is an abstract class.

In actual android implementations, BatteryManagerInternal will be subclassed with an vendor/model dependent class with possible attachments to native code that provide functionality from low-level hardware.

The android SDK library itself is a API for software developers to program upon, it is implementation-independent and for the most part, is free from any lower level hardware code (as these are left up to the implementers of the API).

If you take a look at the source for ServiceManager, which was called on the line:

```
IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService("batteryproperties");
```

within BatteryManager. You'll see its merely a dummy class providing method signatures only with no actual functionality. Again, another example of a something that will be replaced or at least altered from implementation-specific code.

Comment: @user1050491 You would need to find code specific to a device to explore that. I was myself looking for that just now, came up empty.

Comment: I would also be interested, how this is working in general. By BLE? Or HFP?